# Resize multiple images to fit canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, resize

I imported multiple images to make a GIF. The problem is, that the images have multiple resolutions. How can I automatically scale all images to fit the canvas?[image: Screenshot of my layers and the different images, I hope you see them]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where you want to use a script to read the size & position of each layer's bounds so that it can dynamically transform them.

To use this script, copy the code into a plain text document, save, then rename the extension .txt -> .jsx

You can then drag the jsx into Photoshop to run it.

Notes:

- What you're asking for may noticeably stretch some layers if they differ a lot from the canvas size.
- This script is untested. Backup your files before trying it on them just in case.

```
var doc = activeDocument

preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS

var layers = doc.artLayers
var lenLayers = layers.length

for( var i=0; i<lenLayers; i++ ) {  // Loop thru each layer

  var layer = layers[i]

  var bounds = layer.bounds // Bounds is a rectangle [x1,y1,x2,y2]

  // Move to top-left corner
  layer.translate( -bounds[0], -bounds[1] ) 

  // Calculate percent scaling from layer bounds to document (canvas)
  var resizePercentWidth = doc.width / ( bounds[2] - bounds[0] ) * 100
  var resizePercentHeight = doc.height / ( bounds[3] - bounds[1] ) * 100

  layer.resize( resizePercentWidth, resizePercentHeight, AnchorPosition.TOPLEFT )
}
```

If you're interested in learning scripts like this, here are resources to start with:

- https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-scripting-guide-2019.pdf
- https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp

Comment: don't forget to multiply `resizePercentWidth` and `resizePercentHeight` by 100 (you're getting ratio, not percents) and restore user's `rulerUnits`

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I've edited the post.

Comment: I also found a script. I used the script Fit Layer To Canvas from jawinn. Since the script is only for the active layer I tried to change it to apply to all layers. 

The script from jawinn: https://gist.github.com/jawinn/ab4df1c33d0743e41fd3

yours seems to do the trick on all layers. Thanks a lot!

Best regards